# Como mostrar todo datos consultados?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy implementando un sistema de solicitudes de amistad en PHP y MySql.Y por supuesto me funciona,pero solo me muestra un solo resultado,lo que deberia mostrar todos los resultados que encuentre.

Por ejemplo.Juan ha recivido 3 solicitudes.Hay un texto que dicce que ha recivido 3 solicitudes. eso esta bien.Pero a la hora de mostrar las fotos solo me muestra una.y me gustaria que me salieran todas las fotos de los solicitantes.El codigo funciona,no tiene errores.Solo que muestra un solo dato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el codigo php:

```
<?php

   include('verific_sesion.php');
  // login to the database
  $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (User_two = 
   '$my_id' AND Activo = '0')");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);


     if ($row > 0) 
      { // there are new requests


         /*Mensaje que da como salida si existen solicitues nuevas*/
          $mensajito = "<a href='#'>You have ".$row." new friend   
             requests</a>";

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
       {


                 $yo = $row['User_two'];




                        if ($yo == $my_id) 
                        {

                       $solicitante = $row['User_one'];


                          $who = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM personas 
                           WHERE Id = '$solicitante'")or  
                           die(mysqli_error());
                           while ( $delsolicitante = mysqli_fetch_array($who)) {
                                 $requests = "<a href='#'><img width='100px' height='100' src=" .$delsolicitante['Fotos']."> </img></a></br>
                             <button class='boton_aceptar'>Aceptar</button><button class='boton_aceptar'>Eliminar</button></br>";
                            } 



                        }

                             elseif ($row == 0) 
                             {
                                $requests = "";
                             }

          }

   } 

             else
             {

                 $requests =  "No new requests.";
                 /*Mensaje que da como salida si no existen solicitues 
                  nuevas*/
                 $mensajito = "<a href='#'>You have ".$row." new friend 
                requests</a>";
             }



  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el bucle `while` en el que creas los botones para aceptar o eliminar la petición de amigo:

```
while ( $delsolicitante = mysqli_fetch_array($who)) {
    $requests = "<a href='#'><img width='100px' height='100' src=" .$delsolicitante['Fotos']."> </img></a></br>
                 <button class='boton_aceptar'>Aceptar</button><button class='boton_aceptar'>Eliminar</button></br>";
}
```

Si te fijas, estás asignando siempre, eso quiere decir que sólo la última petición se mostrará (porque las peticiones anteriores se sobreescribirán con cada pasada el bucle). La solución es sencilla: concatena (usando `.=`) en lugar de asignar:

```
$requests = "";
while ( $delsolicitante = mysqli_fetch_array($who)) {
    $requests .= "<a href='#'><img width='100px' height='100' src=" .$delsolicitante['Fotos']."> </img></a></br>
                  <button class='boton_aceptar'>Aceptar</button><button class='boton_aceptar'>Eliminar</button></br>";
}
```

Comment: La solucion que me diste funciona.Gracias,pero hay que quitarle la variable que asignaste en la primera linea "$requests = " ",porque sino funciona igual como lo tenia yo.Gracias!!